# Is a metal post base needed on a concrete pier?

Tags: shed, decking, pressure-treated

I'm building a backyard storage shed that will be supported by two 4x6x16' pressure treated rails laying on concrete piers.  The 6" side will be flat against the pier.

[image: concrete pier]

At the building supply store I have seen metal 6x6 post bases that seem to be used for attaching a post to concrete:

[image: post base]

Since I'm using pressure treated lumber, and the piers stick above the ground a bit, do I really need these?  Can the rails sit directly on the concrete?  I can bolt the rails directly to the piers with wedge anchors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sit the rails (or beams) right on the piers and level them using shims. That bracket is used for vertical mounting columns.